# How can I add a close button to my announcement bar on a Shopify website?

Tags: shopify, close-button

There is no option to add a close button when customising the theme, so I will have to add the code manually into the header.liquid file. But I am not sure where or what. Kindly assist.

Comment: You need to have basic knowledge of CSS, HTML, and Javascript for it.

Answer (score 0):

you can add something like that on your header file:

```
<button type="button" class="text-link notification__close" id="NotificationPromoClose"> 
 {% render 'icon-close' %}
  <span class="icon__fallback-text">{{ 'cart.general.close_notification' | t }}</span></button>
```